# Why mongodb doesnt use all the available processing power and memory

Tags: mongodb

Im using MongoDB for storing 1/2 tera bytes of data, the machine is an 8 cores / 14 Gb memory and the OS is Ubuntu.

The question now: Knowing that my MongoDB server is indexing, updating and querying data everytime for an average of 30-40 operations all the time, by using the command `htop` on terminal i can see that it barely reach the 5% of the CPU and 5% of memory. the MongoDB process are still taking a lot time, while it could use the available processing power (at least 60-70%), right ?

Comment: This doesn't really feel like a programming question; it seems to be more about the performance of an application.  This might get better answers in other sites in the network, or from the application vendor directly.

Comment: Normally, [the data files are mmapped](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-lot-of-ram) so MongoDB will use as much RAM as available on your system -- and the OS will swap out pages if an other process need more memory. Could you show the relevant statistics from `(h)top` ?

Comment: Depends on what kind of operations those are.